# Missing archetype.xml in new archetype created from project

Tags: file, maven, archetypes

I am using Maven 2.2.1. and am new to Maven.  I am trying to create an archetype based on an existing project. I have been using this blog post as a guide: http://blog.inflinx.com/category/m2eclipse/

Step 7 says "The next step is to verify that the generated archetype.xml (located under srcmainresourcesMETA-INFmaven (sic))  has all the files listed and they are located in the right directories."

My generated archetype does not have an archetype.xml.  It does have an archetype-metadata.xml file though.  There aren't any errors in the output from calling archetype:create-from-project, just a couple of warnings about using platform encoding (Cp1252).

Any thoughts on why this file wasn't generated?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Archetype.xml is from version 1 of the plugin, whereas the the archetype-metadata.xml is used in version 2+. I don't believe it is a problem, unless people are trying to create projects from the Archetype using Maven 1 which isn't aware of the change in config files.